# Identical C++ program does not work in another directory on Linux

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, debian

I have made a simple program that opens a web camera and sets some properties to it, using OpenCV on Debian 9. It has worked fine for some time using this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( P )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

add_executable( capcheck capcheck.cpp )
target_link_libraries( capcheck ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

However, now when I compile the exact same thing, but in another folder, I get this error when running the program:

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: setting property #21 is not supported
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: Invalid argument
```

Here is the .cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat sketchMat;
    if (!capture.open(1))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Could not open camera " << 1 << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
    capture.set(CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE, 0.25);
    capture.set(CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 0.03);
    capture.read(sketchMat);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: When your code compiles, can you confirm the changes in the camera properties?

Comment: They have no effect. In the other folder, where I don't get the error, the properties clearly change.